# Would it be beneficial to proxy and cache Google Tag Manager

Tags: performance, google-tag-manager, proxy

Google Tag Manager's JS file is not "cached" normally and requires an extra connection to another server (i.e. new SSL handshake and DNS call).

I was wondering is it beneficial to do an Apache proxy cache to the file and refer to it locally setting the caching settings to something more well defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gtm.js is a dynamic library whose contents change with every container version publish. Thus it's not something you should even try to cache, or else your updates to the container might not be recognized by the browsers of returning visitors.

Answer (score 1):

As you've already gathered, the potential benefit of proxying gtm.js would be to eliminate an additional DNS lookup, TCP and TLS handshake, and TCP slow start. If your server supports HTTP/2 and you want to improve the load time of gtm.js, you might want to consider proxying it to reuse the existing connection. This would reuse your existing connection, but would also allow you to push gtm.js if you really wanted to.

If you have typical tracking tags in gtm.js, you may also want to consider how fast you really want gtm.js and related tags to load though. It already load async, and if it only has tracking tags in it, you may slow down the critical rendering path by doing these performance optimizations since there may be contention (e.g. network or CPU usage) with other things that affect rendering, like loading images. On the other hand, if you use it to load a chat widget that you want to show up a lot sooner, maybe this tradeoff is worth it.

I haven't actually tried this, but was considering doing it myself (without push) via Cloudflare Workers. You don't have to cache anything to get the above benefits, but the extra hop will slightly increase load time. You could always just cache for 1 minute at the edge with something like Cloudflare Workers to get freshness plus performance.

The best thing to do is to try this and benchmark with WebPageTest or similar tools. Every site will be different and while this could be beneficial, it could also have bad side effects even if it does speed up GTM.